# Total sales in a period

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Is there an easy way to generate a total net sales figure for a given date range from Shopify? I can see the analytics / reports API but it doesn't appear to return the figure, just generate a report in Shopify.

We need to get the total sales figure (sales minus refunds) for a given period between 2 dates, which might be between 3 months and a year. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. We can generate up to 60 days worth of orders and add the totals, but that seems needlessly resource intensive if you have 1000s of transactions and there's no way to get past orders beyond the 60 days.

Comment: I wrote Profiteer 8, 9 years ago, to do just that. Provide sales reports and COGS with flexible date ranges. Has been quite the ride since then. Clearly, You can do this with a few API calls if you're good at that.